# Iterate through all SVG elements in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, children

I'm not able to go through all children of an SVG file in JavaScript. I want to go through all the paths and perform a function on them(changing them to polygons).

I've tried creating an array of paths using `querySelectorAll("path");`, but it didn't work. Now I'm trying to sift through all the elements in the SVG file, converting paths as I go.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Reader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileReader" />
    <br>
    <p id="Content"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("fileReader").addEventListener('change',function(){
      var fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function(){
        console.log("File Loaded!")
      }
      parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(fr.readAsText(this.files[0]), "text/xml");
      console.log(doc);
      var path = "path";
      doc.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(){
          if($(this).is(path)){
              var polygon = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
              polygon.setAttribute("id", $(this).getAttribute("id"));
              console.log("Converting " + $(this).getAttribute("id"));
              var len = $(this).getTotalLength();
              var p = $(this).getPointAtLength(0);
              var seg = $(this).getPathSegAtLength(0);
              var stp=p.x+","+p.y;
              for(var i=1; i<len; i++){
                p=$(this).getPointAtLength(i);
                if ($(this).getPathSegAtLength(i)>seg) {
                  stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
                  seg = $(this).getPathSegAtLength(i);
                }
              }
              polygon.setAttribute("points", stp);
              $(this).replaceWith(polygon);
          }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives me two errors:

**XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///C:/Users/Temp/Desktop/Experiment.html
Line Number 1, Column 1:**.

**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**.

I've stopped trying to use doc.children() since it wasn't working.

Comment: May you please explain why you need that?

Comment: I've been trying to convert SVG paths to kml polygons, and I've asked over half a dozen questions without getting a proper answer. My solution is to convert SVG path to SVG polygons using JavaScript and then simply print the point in KML format(in the coordinates tag). This has been going on for a couple of weeks and now I'm on edge. Please provide an answer or upvote.

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` The `s` is important. But it seems odd that you would get that error when you're not using the function in your code...

Comment: $ is jquery, you'd need to load the jQuery library but that's going to be a problem as you can't load other files since you're doing this from a file. Best to remove all jquery and rewrite as native DOM calls.

Comment: This is something that I stitched together after learning JS for 2 weeks, with the help of other answers on Stack Overflow. I don't understand jQuery at all, so I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: I finally got it to work. System won't allow me to post the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the jQuery library into your project.

> <script
>   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">

**CODE:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Reader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileReader" />
    <br>
    <p id="Content"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("fileReader").addEventListener('change',function(){
      var fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function(){
        console.log("File Loaded!")
      }
      parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(fr.readAsText(this.files[0]), "text/xml");
      console.log(doc);
      var path = "path";
      doc.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(){
          if($(this).is(path)){
              var polygon = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
              polygon.setAttribute("id", $(this).getAttribute("id"));
              console.log("Converting " + $(this).getAttribute("id"));
              var len = $(this).getTotalLength();
              var p = $(this).getPointAtLength(0);
              var seg = $(this).getPathSegAtLength(0);
              var stp=p.x+","+p.y;
              for(var i=1; i<len; i++){
                p=$(this).getPointAtLength(i);
                if ($(this).getPathSegAtLength(i)>seg) {
                  stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
                  seg = $(this).getPathSegAtLength(i);
                }
              }
              polygon.setAttribute("points", stp);
              $(this).replaceWith(polygon);
          }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```